# Axios Request Not Following Proxy Configuration

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, http, axios

I have a frontend development setup where I'm using a local frontend development server running on port 5173. My backend server is running on port 5500. I've set up a proxy in my frontend project's package.json to redirect requests to the backend server:

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5500",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext js,jsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.5",
    "axios": "^1.4.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.10.1",
    "react-redux": "^8.1.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.15.0",
    "react-toastify": "^9.1.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.2.15",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.7",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.0.3",
    "eslint": "^8.45.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.32.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.3",
    "vite": "^4.4.5"
  }
}
```

However, when I make Axios requests, the requests are still being sent to http://localhost:5173 instead of http://localhost:5500, causing issues with communication to the backend server. Here's my Axios code:

```
import axios from 'axios';

// Set the base URL for Axios requests
const API_URL = '/api/users/';

// Register user
const register = async (userData) => {
  const response = await axios.post(API_URL, userData);

  if (response.data) {
    localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(response.data));
  }

  return response.data;
};

const authService = { register };
export default authService;
```

I've double-checked the proxy configuration and verified that there are no typos. I've also tried restarting the frontend server, clearing my browser cache, and ensuring the backend server has CORS properly configured. Despite these efforts, the requests are still being sent to the wrong port. Any suggestions on how to fix this issue would be greatly appreciated.